# Save gulp plug-ins in project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying out Gulp to automate the creation of a ZIP file to distribute my PHP project. I'm not very familiar yet with npm.

I've already realised that I'll need several plug-ins (gulp-asvn and gulp-zip so far). I've installed them following the instructions provided in the official site, e.g.:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-asvn
```

My node_modules directory is already as large as the actual codebase and, being just an internal developer tool, I wouldn't like to commit it into my Subversion repository if I don't have to.

Is there a way to tell npm what packages are required and have the possibility to get them installed at once, so when others checkout the code don't have too many problems configuring their environment? In PHP's Composer you'd have a `composer.json` file but I'm not sure if `package.json` is equivalent to that, and `npm install` has not created it anyway.

Comment: we use `npm init` to install `package.json` which includes the dependencies required for the node module to run. You can list all the dependencies in it which is required and then just execute `npm install` to install all the dependencies listed in `package.json` at once.

Comment: @Sumit All answers were useful but your comment was the key. The `--save-dev` parameter has no effect if you don't have a `package.json` already. I was confused by `composer require` which creates all files automatically. If you post a proper answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: sure I will frame the answer and post it. Kindly suggest edits to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project dependencies are stored in a `package.json` file but `npm install --save-dev` **will not create the file** if it doesn't exist, or even warn that it doesn't exist and the `--save-dev` switch will have no effect. (In this sense, it behaves differently than Composer, which just creates its `composer.json` file automatically.)

The bare minimum configuration for a project that's not a redistributable JavaScript library can be as small as this:

```
{
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**
If your dependencies are named in the `package.json` file your fine.
The user has just to say to `npm` to install them: `npm install`.

**Long story**

Say you have your `package.json` file.

Now you do

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-asvn
```

This will install the `gulp-asvn` package and add it to the `package.json` file as `devDependencies`.

If you're ignoring the `node_modules` from the checked files, the user has just to say `npm` to install all the dependencies and you're fine.

```
npm install
```

This command looks inside the `package.json`, resolves all the dependencies and the dev dependencies, pull them down from the `npm` registry and install them.

Comment: I suspect the missing bit is `npm init` because `--save-dev` is not saving anything as far as I can tell. I'll check that and report back.

Comment: `npm init` will create your `package.json` file. You can create it also manually.

Answer (score 1):

Referring from composer docs -

*This idea is not new and Composer is strongly inspired by node's npm and ruby's bundler.*

You can use this command to make sure that you ignore node_modules folder to be committed to svn repo.

```
  svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Your default text editor will pop up and you can add node_modules directory to be ignored according to your folder structure.

Now as you know that npm 'may' not be around for a long time. To be on safe side you can create another repo for node_modules.

Also you can keep your dependencies and dev-dependencies differentiated and kept separately in your package.json file.

```
  npm install
```

P.S. - Above command is more than enough for someone else to configure their environment. If not you can use environment variables for api keys and other environment dependent constants.

Answer (score 1):

*Node modules are installed in the folder if that has file `package.json`.
The `package.json` has many fields which tells about the author, git repository etc.*

There is one important field here, which is `dependencies:` that basically lists the node modules that are required to run this project. When `npm install somePackage --save-dev` is run, It tries to find `package.json` and saves it as a dependency in it while also downloading the module.

You can create `package.json` by writing `npm init` and listing all the node modules in the dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "gulp-asvn": "^0.4.5",
  "....." : ".."
},
```

and run `npm install`.

You can also save dependencies by individually running `npm install --save-dev gulp-asvn` and other packages. It will be then added in your `package.json`